CGI movie what looks like a talking cow or bull. (screenshot included)
I was browsing through Netflix the other day and stumbled upon this.

I'm guessing this isn't a shot from Hitler and the Nazis, so I was curious what it really was from.

Could it be Barnyard?

Thanks.  IMDB page for Barnyard shows a screenshot of the same character.  Someone want to add this as an answer and I'll upvote it?

The crossover produces Animal Farm.

It is definitely Barnyard. There is also a tv show with the same characters Back to the Barnyard, but it is currently not on Netflix. 
